# jQuery append is not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append

I have an issue with the append function. It works on chrome and firefox but not IE.

This is my code:

```
$('a#ajouterTarification').click(function() { 
    $("#append_tarification").append($("<div>").load("./server/hotels-ajouter-tarifications.php?i="+i).fadeIn(700));
    $('#nb_lignes_tarification').val(i);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Already tried to break the things apart? First create the div, than do the load, than append...etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be caused by .load and .fadeIn in .append. I haven't tested it but  try the following:

```
$('a#ajouterTarification').click(function() { 

    var $div = $("<div/>"); // First store the new div in a variable

    $("#append_tarification").append($div); // Then append

    $div.load("./server/hotels-ajouter-tarifications.php?i="+i).fadeIn(700); // Do whatever you want with div

    $('#nb_lignes_tarification').val(i);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks TJ for the answer, but the problem is still the same with ie.

Comment: Just to give us something to work with I've created an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tangibleJ/6Lv85/2/. I've replaced load with html to make things a bit easier. I tested with FF6 and IE8.

Comment: thanks again, and sorry i was trying to resolve the problem before i post again. Yeah I tried this code on jsfiddle and it works but i guess the problem is with this line: $div.load("./server/hotels-ajouter-tarifications.php?i="+i).fadeIn(700); because this code works properly $div.html('loaded content').fadeIn(700);

Comment: to analyze the problem further we'd need to know what is being loaded. At least you now know where the problem lies.

Comment: hi, my function is used to load form elements: inputs, select, checkboxes... etc
this is a screen capture containing an example: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/loadn.png/

Answer (score 0):

Try appendTo instead of append.  That way, the div gets into your DOM before you start operating on it.

```
$('a#ajouterTarification').click(function() { 
    $("<div>").appendTo("#append_tarification").load("./server/hotels-ajouter-tarifications.php?i="+i).fadeIn(700);
    $('#nb_lignes_tarification').val(i);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Denis for the answer but appendTo gives the same result. It works on chrome and firefox but not ie.